# Adding views/tmpl to Joomla Plugin

Tags: joomla

I need a advice on how to add some different views/tmpls to a Joomla 3.x System Plugin. I made a simple plugin to replace Joomla 3.x Offline page, but i would like to add several different views (layouts) to that plugin. I am confused with views vs tmpl. Could some one give me some guidance and give me a simple directory structure to follow.

I use this code to trigger \views\defaultview\view.html.php but i want to have more different views. Is this the correct way?

```
public function onBeforeRender(){
    // Get the application.
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    if (($app->getCfg('offline'))&&(!$app->isAdmin())) {
    // Get the document object.
    $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
    $view = 'defaultview';
    $basePath = __DIR__;
    $config = array( 'base_path'=>$basePath);
    require_once $basePath . DS . 'views'  . DS . $view . DS . 'view.html.php';
    JResponse::setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    JResponse::sendHeaders();       

    $app->close();
    }
}
```

Thanks. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You don't provide much information (e.g. Joomla version, code showing what you've tried etc) but here goes…

`View`s and `tmpl`s are part of the [MVC of Joomla `components`](http://docs.joomla.org/Model-View-Controller) not [`plugin`](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin_Developer_Overview)s. Plugins are small pieces of code that respond to [`events`](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events). If you're not clear on them read the linked articles.

Having, said that, it is possible to affect the loading of a `view` or it's `tmpl` but how you want to use it will depend on your existing code. Depending on whether you're on Joomla 3.x or Joomla 2.5.x you will probably benefit from reading through the tutorials about developing an MVC component, the [2.5.x version here](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction) or the [3.x version here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Introduction).

`Tmpl` files are effectively templated pieces of code that are loaded by the `view`, a `tmpl` file can also load a sub-`tmpl` file easily. e.g. `/tmpl/default.php` can load `/tmpl/default-tools.php` with a single call (originally they were meant to be flexible and reusable pieces of code but for various reasons that doesn't work in practice). They can be overridden by the template in use for any given page.

In the recent releases of the J3 line, `layouts` are now available. These *are* small, flexible pieces of code that can be used and re-used in various places through-out Joomla, and they can be provided by third-party extensions, and overridden at the template.

If you can provide more details about your particular usage scenario, code etc we can probably provide more help.

Failing that as this question is about Joomla specific implementation details, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com).